# Grab text contained within PHP-generated element

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble grabbing the actual text within a header tag that is generated by some PHP code. Here's the portion of the page that I'm grabbing.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="majorContainer">
    <h2>Your results for: <small>"tables"</small></h2>
    <hr />
    <div class='accordionButton'>
      <h3 style="display:inline">1. </h3>
      <h3 style="display:inline" id='major-1'>Electrical Engineering Technology</h3>
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
    <div class='accordionButton'>
      <h3 style="display:inline">2. </h3>
      <h3 style="display:inline" id='major-2'>Retail Management</h3>
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
```

Basically, when the user clicks on an 'accordionButton', I want to pull the text from the header tag of that specific button. In my PHP, I assigned an ID to each header tag because I figured I could just pull the text doing:

```
document.getElementById(this.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0].id).text
```

When I alerted this in a message box, I'm only seeing 'undefined'. I tried, instead, just doing...

```
$(this).text()
```

...but this returned "1. Electrical Engineering Technology..." which is not what I want. I just want the title "Electrical Engineering Technology" that is contained in the h3 tag.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this help? I am using jquery 1.7.1.

```
$(".accordionButton").on("click", function(){
   alert($(this).find("h3").eq(1).text()); 
});
```

If you need to learn more about jquery, here is a very good link to start with http://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much! Could you briefly explain how that works, though, just for my own understanding?

Comment: when you click on the element with the class ".accordionButton", jquery searches or finds for second h3 (eq(1) as index starts from 0).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).find("h3:last").text();
```

As DG3 points out, you can't just select by ID - I was ignoring the original request. I have amended this answer to reflect the actual solution.

Comment: you just can't use an ID. There are multiple elements with the class "accordionButton", and h3 with the id "major-1" is related only to first accordion.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.accordionButton').click(function(){
    alert( $(this).find('h3:last').text())
});
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/Mq4JS/